# How can I put the input of showInputDialog in variable?

Tags: java

I want to ask the user to input integers in showInputDialog, but if the input is non-integer value then the catch will work.

Can anyone guide me to the right direction?

```
public static void tryCatch(){
    try{
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome");
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter your number");

        int pass = Integer.parseInt(null);

    } catch(InputMismatchException e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid number!");
    }   
}
```

Comment: `String inputString = JOptionPane.showInput...`. Then parse the `inputString`

Comment: Also make sure to catch the right exception. Trying to parse invalid integer will give you a `NumberFormatException`

Answer (score 2):

If you have a read of the [JavaDocs for `JOptionPane.showInputDialog`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog(java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object)), you will see that...

> Returns:
>  user's input, or null meaning the user canceled the input

This means you can assign the result that is returned from the method call to a variable, something like...

```
String text = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter your number");
```

See [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) and the [JavaDocs for `JOptionpane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example

```
import javax.swing.*;

/**
 * JOptionPane showInputDialog example #1.
 * A simple showInputDialog example.
 * 
 */
public class JOptionPaneShowInputDialogExample1
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
   // a jframe here isn't strictly necessary, but it makes the example a little more real
   JFrame frame = new JFrame("InputDialog Example #1");

   // prompt the user to enter their num
   int num;

  do {

        try
                {
                    num= Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "Enter the     number"));
                    break;
                }

                catch (NumberFormatException e)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                            "Error. Please enter a valid number", "Error",
                            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                }

    } while (true)
   // get the user's input. note that if they press Cancel, 'name' will be null
   System.out.printf("The user's name is '%d'.\n", num);
   System.exit(0);
```

}
}

Comment: what type of exception should i use? i tried to write characters but my exception still doesn't work

Comment: If you expect number then catch NumberFormatException

Comment: @mazin - i have edited my code to suite your scenario with catching NumberFormatException. I hope it helps !!!